# Server.UrlEncode & Server.UrlDecode

Tags: c#, asp.net

I don't know, Why do we use `Server.UrlEncode()` & `Server.UrlDecode()`?!
in QueryString we see anything in URL, so why do we want encode or decode them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The URLEncode method applies URL encoding rules, including escape
>   characters, to a specified string.
>
> URLEncode converts characters as follows:
>
> Spaces ( ) are converted to plus signs (+).
>
> Non-alphanumeric characters are escaped to their hexadecimal
>   representation.

Also, I think you are talking about `HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode` method which decodes the encoded string and returnes you back the original string.

> URL-decodes a string and returns the decoded string
>
> URL encoding ensures that all browsers will correctly transmit text in
>   URL strings. Characters such as a question mark (?), ampersand (&),
>   slash mark (/), and spaces might be truncated or corrupted by some
>   browsers. As a result, these characters must be encoded in  tags or
>   in query strings where the strings can be re-sent by a browser in a
>   request string.
>
> UrlDecode is a convenient way to access the HttpUtility.UrlDecode
>   method at run time from an ASP.NET application. Internally, UrlDecode
>   uses HttpUtility.UrlDecode to decode strings.

More info ...

[Server.URLEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738(v=vs.90).aspx)

[HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

[It is taken from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

URLEncode converts characters as follows:

> ```
> Spaces ( ) are converted to plus signs (+).
>
> Non-alphanumeric characters are escaped to their hexadecimal representation.
> ```

```
<%Response.Write(Server.URLEncode("http://www.microsoft.com")) %> 

produces the following output:

http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Emicrosoft%2Ecom
```

Comment: Mesut Darvishian you are Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Some characters are not legal in URLs, so they must be encoded. [This](http://dslrphotoforum.com/index.php?topic=211.0) was the first hit I found for a list of illegal characters.