# White-space issue while accessing the database field from SQL-Server 2008 into asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to retrieve one of the database field from`sql server 2008` with the following code,In the database the data field is named as `OBGST & GYNAECOLOGY` which has a `ampersand` in it.
Now when i am retrieving in asp.net only the first text before ampersand is been displayed as
`OBGST`,but the actual result should be `OBGST & GYNAECOLOGY`.

I have tried the following code but still didn't get rid of this issue.

```
 literal.Text = "<script>window.open('UploadFiles.aspx?dept="+deptname+"&hosno=" + hosno + "&visitno=" + visitno + "','_blank')</script>";

 txtdept.Text = Request.QueryString["dept"].ToString().Replace("%20&%20", "&");
```

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654057/server-urlencode-server-urldecode](Server.UrlEncode & Server.UrlDecode)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the whitespace, but the ampersand. URLEncode it: `%26`, in your `literal.Text`.

Comment: Actually, in the `Literal.Text` he should be using `Server.UrlDecode(...)` since at this point he's not using the value from the database.

Comment: @bastos.sergio I'd say `deptname` is what he gets from his DB and he should UrlEncode it to make sure the web client understands it.

Comment: Can you explain it in details?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reqex to remove extra space

Regex.Replace(YOURTEXT, @"\s+", "")

This will remove any space within text.